# Transaction Synchronization for a custom inbound channel adapter

Tags: spring-integration

I implemented a custom `<inbound-channel-adapter>` that extends `MessageProducerSupport`, a little bit like `ImapIdleChannelAdapter` from spring integration. The goal of this inbound channel adapter is to launch a **persistent** search on LDAP, and each time there's a new change in LDAP, it sends the change to a channel afterwards to an `<int-http:outbound-channel-adapter>`. However I would like to when the message is successfully sent to be able to log it into a database as processed. Would you please help me to accomplish this task with some ideas? Thank you very much!

Comment: If you have some additional question you can simply comment to the answer and I'll take care about further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve that make `channel` for that `<int-http:outbound-channel-adapter>` as `publish-subscribe` and add one more `<int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter>` to it.

This second subscriber will be invoked only when the first one has finished its work. And in this case the same `Message` will be sent to the DB adapter.

Another option is based on the `<request-handler-advice-chain>` together with `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`, when you can specify the `onSuccessExpression` together with `successChannel` to send something to another channel on good result of adapter handling.

Comment: I thank you very much for your answer.I would like to know wether it's also guaranteed that the second subscriber will be invoked only when the first subscriber had completed the task successfully if I use a simple `<int:service-activator>` as a second subscriber or `<int-mongo:outbound-channel-adapter>`. and talking about `<request-handler-advice-chain>` how can I use the payload in order to save it to my database if I use this solution? what kind of `onSuccessExpression` should I use? Thank you evry much!

Comment: Here is a guaranty https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/dispatcher/BroadcastingDispatcher.java#L158 with default options. `onSuccessExpression` - `#root`, where it is just that `requestMessage`.